# Subsequent Row Date/Time difference in SQL Server to calculate machine cycle time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'd like to calculate in SQL server the cycle time in seconds of each ocurrance.

It's the difference between the current row 'TimeCol' and the following 'TimeCol'.

[image: Screenshot]

The desired answer is to have a calculated column that show the time spent on the current model.

```
TimeCol                          model_code              cycle_seconds
2021-07-08 16:02:25              9011                   185
2021-07-08 16:05:30              9016                   484623
2021-07-14 06:42:33              9016                   0
2021-07-14 06:42:33              9011                   31
2021-07-14 06:43:04
```

Any help will be much appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: With lag, you compare to the previous row, I need the difference with the next row.

Thanks for replying

Comment: ... The previous row is the next row if you reverse the order, @Drac ... Or, you could use `LEAD`.

Comment: @Larnu thanks, it worked. Any idea how to make a new table/view so it includes this calculated value(T_Ciclo)?

WITH cont AS (
  SELECT
    *,
 rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TimeCol)
  FROM tbscxDraxtonTeruelProgeltaKunkelPouring
)
SELECT
  cur.*,DATEDIFF(second,cur.TimeCol,next.TimeCol) T_Ciclo
FROM cont cur
INNER JOIN cont next on next.rownum = cur.rownum + 1

Comment: A table can't use `LAG`/`LEAD` as a computed column, @Drac . You would need to use a `VIEW`.